# Are abstract class constructors not implicitly called when a derived class is instantiated?

Tags: php, abstract-class

Take this example:

```
abstract class Base {
    function __construct() {
        echo 'Base __construct<br/>';
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    function __construct() {
        echo 'Child __construct<br/>';
    }
}

$c = new Child();
```

Coming from a C# background, I expect the output to be

> Base __construct
>  Child __construct

However, the actual output is just

> Child __construct

Answer (score 113, accepted):

No, the constructor of the parent class is not called if the child class defines a constructor.

From the constructor of your child class, you have to call the constructor of the parent's class :

```
parent::__construct();
```

Passing it parameters, if needed.

Generally, you'll do so at the beginning of the constructor of the child class, before any specific code ; which means, in your case, you'd have :

```
class Child extends Base {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'Child __construct<br/>';
    }
}
```

And, for reference, you can take a look at this page of the PHP manual : [Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) -- it states *(quoting)* :

> **Note:**  Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. 
> In order to
>   run a parent constructor, a call to
>   `parent::__construct()` within the
>   child constructor is required.

Comment: The do not explicitly state this but they imply that if the child class does not have a constructor, then the parent constructor will be called. Is that true?

Comment: Yes : if the child class doesn't define a constructor, the parent's one is not overriden, and, so, is called ;;; quoting the manual : Parent constructors are not called implicitly **if the child class defines a constructor**.

Comment: @PascalMARTIN Thank you, was looking around trying to verify that. Took a little bit of searching.

Answer (score 9):

Well, I just found this in the [docs](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> Note:  Parent constructors are not
>   called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run
>   a parent  constructor, a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child
>   constructor is required.

Comment: The main reason I write a constructor in an abstract class is to enforce that every class that inherits from this class executes the code specified.

It's a real shame PHP makes the execution of the constructor optional.

Comment: @RyanWilliams There are cases where you need to call parent constructor before doing some extra initialization in class and there are cases when the parent is called after extra initializations. So PHP allows you too support more use cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the same behaviour as C#, that is the parent constructor gets always executed before child constructor, you could create a fake constructor class for your child classes and declare it as an abstract function in your abstract parent class.

E.g.

```
abstract class Test{
  abstract public function __childconstruct();
  public function __construct(){
    echo "SOME CODE".PHP_EOL;
    $this->__childconstruct();
  }
}

class TestExtended extends Test{
  public function __childconstruct(){
    echo "SOME OTHER CODE FROM EXTENDED CLASS".PHP_EOL;
  }
}

$a = new TestExtended();

/* SOME CODE
   SOME OTHER CODE FROM EXTENDED CLASS */
```

Comment: This also solves the problem when you need to enforce child classes to define actions on construct, but also to define base behaviour in parent (PHP does not allow abstract constructors with a body `{...}`)