# What pitfalls should be noted when moving from C# to PHP?

Tags: c#, php

So, I just stumbled across this one in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321009/are-abstract-class-constructors-not-implicitly-called-when-a-derived-class-is-ins):

> Parent constructors are not called
>   implicitly if the child class defines
>   a constructor.

What else should one be aware of when writing code in PHP from a C# background?

Comment: Those are two totally different languages ; I suppose the best solution for you would be to take the time to go through the manual ;; if not the full functions-list, at least the Language Reference part ( http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php ) is probably a must-read ;-) ;; and as you already know how to develop with a modern language, a quick-read should be quite enough.

Comment: I don't agree that the are **totally** different. Maybe the way the languages are interpreted, variable scope, but structure seems to be fairly consistent. Both have namespaces, classes, types, etc. It would be nice to have one place to reference some of the *pit falls* not just language semantics.

Comment: The OP is asking for non-obvious pitfalls (i.e. Things that won't be apparant after skimming documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [an article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/asp-net-for-php-developers/) that discusses C# from the PHP point of view. This should help you out some with knowing what's alike and what'd different between the two languages.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are too numerous to count, really. I suggest getting some kind of introductory literature on PHP. Both are extremely different languages.